# Stored Procedure en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenos días quería saber como puedo hacer para que en el siguiente código implementar un **stored procedure**.

Una parte del código:

```
class ControladorUsuarios
{
    static public function ctrIngresoUsuario()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["ingUsuario"])) {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])) {
                $tabla     = "usuarios";
                $item      = "usuario";
                $valor     = $_POST["ingUsuario"];
                $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esta parte del código es donde me conecto con la base de datos y me trae los datos correctamente:

```
require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios
{
    static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor)
    {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
        $stmt->bindParam(":" . $item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

lo que intento es implementar el **stored procedure** siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el intento que hice es el siguiente código que no dio resultado cuando intente llamar al SP no sé cómo seria la forma correcta.

```
require_once "conexion.php";

class ModeloUsuarios
{
    static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($valor)
    {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("Call C7 ($valor) ");
        $stmt->bindParam($valor, PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

El stored procedure anterior es un ejemplo solo para saber como implementarlo en el código, espero alguien pueda ayudarme o brindarme un ejemplo, ya que recién estoy empezando con PHP.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Disculpa, ¿qué es lo que buscas cambiar en el SP que muestras como ejemplo?

Comment: @Alfabravo no intento cambiar el SP sino saber como se llama el desde el codigo php yo hice un intento que escribi pero no logre hacerlo.

Comment: @Bicho en el intento que hice que esta escrito mi codigo de llamar un SP  no puede llamar al SP

Comment: Ah! Vale, recuerda siempre mostrar claramente qué error te genera el código que estés intentando usar.

Answer (score 0):

Para llamar el procedimiento almacenado desde tu código en PHP, es necesario que añadas la variable de entrada de otra forma, ya que estás buscando hacer el `prepare` de la sentencia correctamente.

```
<?php

. . .
// Haces el prepared statement pero le indicas que lleva un parámetro de entrada
$stmt = $connection->prepare("CALL C7(?)");
// Haces el bind de parámetros para el prepared statement
$stmt->bind_param("valor", $valor); 

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$response = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Haces aquí algo con tu resultado

$stmt->close();
$connection->close();
```